# CPort not work properly with windows 10

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, windows-10, tcomport

**RESOLVED**
*Just update Windows 10 and the problem disappears*

---

I have an old program developed with Delphi 7 and uses TComPort for serial communication.

On windows 10 TComPort wrong to enumerate the ports, it does not return the port number.

The program works perfectly from windows xp to windows 8.1 u1

So there is an incompatibility between Windows 10 and TComPort, setting the compatibility, or by running the program as an administrator does not change anything.

How can I fix?
I have to use another library for serial communication?

Here's a test I've done

```
    unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, CPort;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComPort1: TComPort;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var List:TStringList;
    sPortName:String;
    I:integer;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    EnumComPorts( List );
    For I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
      begin
      sPortName := Trim(List[I]);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(sPortName);
      end;

  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

This is the result

[image: Output]

The string "sPortName" is 3 characters long.

Comment: ComPort gets known serial ports from registry key  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,    'HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM'. Does it exist in W10? Is it available due to permission rules?

Comment: yes, there is this key with the following values
\Device\USBSER000 COM5
\Device\USBSER001 COM6 but when I start the program as a list of two COM ports without number. like "COM" and not "COM5"

Comment: Try some debugging to investigate where it goes wrong.

Comment: TComPort's EnumComPorts has a unicode problem. Maybe this is related? See https://sourceforge.net/p/comport/bugs/38/ .

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues in the past with TComPort returning port names. TComPort is working fine for me here with Windows 10. I have found it is necessary to use Trim() on each returned port name since #0 characters can get returned at the end of the port name. You do not provide any useful debugging info but this may be contributing to your issue. The solution is simple. I do:

```
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    EnumComPorts( List );
    For I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
      begin
      sPortName := Trim(List[I]);
      <<< do something with sPortName >>>
      end;

  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: It does not work, now I change, the initial post with an example

Comment: `EnumComPorts` will add #0 and random data, because there is a unicode bug in this function. `Trim` will not always work. The correct solution is to modify `CPort.pas`, see https://sourceforge.net/p/comport/bugs/38/ .